# How to make sure Mortal Era addition signed invariant?

Tags: era

CheckMortality `additional_signed` seems variant between blocks(I add some log to check_mortality.rs):
[image: era mortal]

I have a usecase that need `additional_signed` result of Era invariant between some adjacent blocks(in Era period). I know that the signature depend on Era,TxVersion etc.

i.e. I generate a signature#1 based on payload in block#1. then I want to validate this signature#1 in block#2. When in block#2, I generate another signature#2 with the same payload, and compare it with signature#1. But because signature#2 use different Era's addition signed, those two signature is different.
[image: verification signature]
So how to make sure signature invariant between blocks, and also use Era as addition signed?